# Loop through file tree and change permissions selectively

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have a main _web folder wich is holding this structure of folders and files(see below). I am trying to make a bash script which would loop through all the folders and change permissions for files to 640 and directories to 750.

Any suggestion on how could I do this?

```
/_web/www_svetaine1  - a.html      
                     - b.html
                     - index.html
                 /pictures - a.jpg
                           - b.jpg
                           - c.jpg
                                /icons/a.jpg
/_web/www_svetaine2  - a.html       
                     - b.html
                     - index.html
                 /pictures - a.jpg
                           - b.jpg
                           - c.jpg
                                /icons/a.jpg
/_web/ftp_serveris1  - a.doc    
                     - b.doc
            /visiems - c.doc

/_web/ftp_serveris2  - a.doc    
                     - b.doc   
            /visiems - c.doc
```

Comment: Please rewrite your title. A proper title is meant to help others with similar problem in the futur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /_web -type d -exec chmod 750 {} +
find /_web -type f -exec chmod 640 {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find ./_web -type f -exec chmod -v 640 {} \;
find ./_web -type d -exec chmod -v 750 {} \;
```